# Can I bypass all setTimeouts in Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I realized that my test suite is running code with `setTimeout`s. As it stands, if I use `useFakeTimers`, my test suite breaks. I can't go through all the tests to figure each issue one at a time right now. I am hoping to bypass all timeouts by just instantly running their callbacks like this:

```js
jest
  .spyOn(global, 'setTimeout')
  .mockImplementation((callback) => callback());
```

`TS` tells me `This expression is not callable. No constituent of type 'TimerHandler' is callable.`

I also tried hacking it like this:

```js
// in beforeEach
jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');

// in test
const callback = mocked(global.setTimeout).mock.calls[0][0] as Function;
callback();
```

I am fairly sure I had done things like this in the past to make sure that any setTimeout callback is instantly run instead of waiting. How can I accomplish this still? I know it's not the best idea but I'm time-limited right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never should, but technically can `setTimeout` take a string that will get `eval`'d. I assuming that `TimerHandler` type covers this use case. So the types won't let you assume that the callback is always a function.

You should be able to fix it by double checking that the callback is a function:

```
jest
  .spyOn(global, 'setTimeout')
  .mockImplementation((callback) => typeof callback === 'function' ? callback() : null);
```

Using this on my own environment I got this test to pass just fine:

```
describe('foo', () => {
  it('foo', () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(global, 'setTimeout')
      .mockImplementation((callback) => (typeof callback === 'function' ? callback() : null))
    let foo = 0
    setTimeout(() => (foo = 123), 100000)
    expect(foo).toEqual(123)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks yeah you are right I shouldn't do this but now I need to get a test working and then separately go back to remove this hack later. :)

Answer (score 1):

For TypeScript, You can try this

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout').mockImplementation((callback) => {
if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback();
}
return { hasRef: () => false } as NodeJS.Timeout;
});
```